# hasattr v. membership testing of __dict__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm defining a Field class instances of which may be nested. The ultimate goal is to interact with memory mapped hardware registers on an embedded device from the command line. As an example here is the result of `print(nop)`:

```
nop       1000000001000000 0X8040 32832    
  error   ........0100.... 0X4    4     CIP
    bit_0 ...........0.... 0X0    0     NO 
    bit_1 ..........0..... 0X0    0     NO 
    bit_2 .........1...... 0X1    1     YES
    bit_3 ........0....... 0X0    0     NO 
  fault   1............... 0X1    1
```

My first attempt was to implement `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` but that lead to this kind of interaction:

```
> nop['error']['bit_0'] = 'NO'

> nop['fault'] = 1
```

This will be pretty cumbersome so it occurred to me that I might use `__getattr__` instead as it would allow me to interact as follows:

```
> nop.error.bit_0 = 'NO'

> nop.fault = 1
```

With a shell that supports autocomplete things will be even easier.

Basically I need to identify a child field by name and return or assign its value. Here's my implementation of these methods:

```
def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    try:
        self.__getattr__(key).value(value)
    except AttributeError:
        super().__setattr__(key, value)

def __getattr__(self, key):
    if '_children' in self.__dict__:
        for child in self._children:
            if child.name() == key:
                return child

    raise AttributeError
```

I'm pretty happy with this but notice that I am testing membership of `_children` in `__dict__`. If I use `hasattr` I get infinite recursion.

Is this a flawed approach? What is fundamentally wrong with testing `__dict__` membership.

Update:

Per Martijn Pieters I added the check for `_children` to `__setattr__`, I removed the check for `_children` from `__getattr__`, and I assign `_children` first in `__init__`. The result is `RecursionError` during a deep copy which I perform when a child is added:

```
def add_child(self, child, position):

    assert position >= 0

    child = copy.deepcopy(child)

    # Coerce the child to be orphaned and positioned at 0 for the following tests.

    child._position = 0

    child._parent = None

    ...
```

Results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kenny/Development/CCL/OCE/field.py", line 308, in <module>
    error.add_child(child_child, i)
  File "/home/kenny/Development/CCL/OCE/field.py", line 140, in add_child
    child = copy.deepcopy(child)
  File "/home/kenny/Miniconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/home/kenny/Miniconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 299, in _reconstruct
    if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
  File "/home/kenny/Development/CCL/OCE/field.py", line 18, in __getattr__
    for child in self._children:
  File "/home/kenny/Development/CCL/OCE/field.py", line 18, in __getattr__
    for child in self._children:
    .
    .
    .
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hasattr()` uses `getattr()` to test for the presence of an attribute, so yes, using `hasattr()` in `getattr()` will lead to infinite recursion.

Test for `_children` in `__setattr__`:

```
def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    if key == '_children':
        return super().__setattr__(key, value)
    try:
        self.__getattr__(key).value(value)
    except AttributeError:
        super().__setattr__(key, value)
```

because *at some point* you'll want to be able to do `self._children = []`.

If you set `self._children` as the first attribute in `__init__` you  don't need to test for `_children` in `__getattr__` anymore; all instances will have that attribute then (and `__setattr__` ensured it was set):

```
def __getattr__(self, key):
    for child in self._children:
        if child.name() == key:
            return child
    raise AttributeError
```

Remember, `__getattr__` is only called for attributes that are missing from the instance, while `__setattr__` is called for *all* attributes.

To avoid your infinite recursion problem, I'd simply ignore all attributes that start with `_`:

```
def __getattr__(self, key):
    # ignore private attributes
    if key[:1] != '_':
        for child in self._children:
            if child.name() == key:
                return child
    raise AttributeError
```

This neatly avoids all issues with attempted access to `self._children` as well, since it starts with an underscore.

Comment: I tried defining `_children` first and declared victory then ran in to a recursion issue when using `copy.deepcopy`!

Comment: I don't think the special case for `_children` in `__setattr__` is necessary, since the `__getattr__` call in the `try` block will fail with an `AttributeError` if the attribute doesn't exist.

Comment: @Kenny: what issue was that?

Comment: @Blckknght: I prefer to be explicit about this; future attempts to set `instance._children` should not need to iterate over all the `_children` iterable first.

Comment: There was another recursion limit exception that I didn't quite understand. It was down in the pickling routines. When I add a child I deep copy the child.

Comment: @Kenny: without seeing the traceback that's not something I can help with I fear.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understand. I'll see if I can re-create it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Updated question to include recursion error.

Comment: @Kenny: note the `hasattr()` call for `__setstate__`. You could ignore all attributes that start with `_` in `__getattr__` to avoid that one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I could and this would help me avoid testing membership in `__dict__` but what is fundamentally wrong with testing `__dict__`? I'll revise my question to include this.

Comment: @Kenny: you don't need to at all, because `__getattr__` will not be called for attributes that are in `__dict__`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. I'll mark this as a solution as it does eliminate the `__dict__` check and I'll post another question asking why this is a bad idea.