# Why is testing membership of `__dict__` poor form?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34642695/873389) regarding eliminating a test of membership of `__dict__` for an object. A solution was provided but it was somewhat less elegant that using `if x in __dict__`.

As I mentioned in that post I would have preferred to use `hasattr` but it led to a `RecursionError`.

What is wrong with the test of membership?

Comment: I am not going to flag it as such, but I have feeling that this question would be better suited to [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); or maybe [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you can add some working code that can be discussed.

Comment: Consider what would happen if something tested `__dict__` of the class you defined `__getattr__` for. It wouldn't see the same members that `hasattr` would.

Comment: @MirosławZalewski: It would be best suited _here_ if the OP can add the broken code under discussion.

Comment: It's fragile and error prone.  What's wrong with try/except instead, as Martian Peters has already suggested for you there.  Much more elegant and pythonic!

Comment: @MirosławZalewski: I think you are correct that Code Review would have been a better choice. I actually wasn't aware of that sister site.

Comment: @wim It's fragile and error prone perhaps but why? I can except that it might be poor form I'm just trying to understand why that might be.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There is no broken code. I'm just trying to understand why this might be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure that I understand your other post, but note that `__dict__` only contains the attributes of the instance -- not the class.  e.g.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   x = 1
... 
>>> Foo().__dict__
{}
```

However, a `hasattr` call will tell you that an instance of `Foo` does have an `x` attribute:

```
>>> hasattr(Foo(), 'x')
True
```

So, whatever the case, we can see that these two idioms have different meanings -- even under certain pretty common circumstances.

Comment: And `__dict__` doesn't necessarily even contain the attributes of an instance (or even exist), if the class uses the rarer, more efficient `__slots__` storage strategy.

Comment: @JonathanEunice -- Yep, but those are more exotic objects.  I wanted to show a more simple example where there is a difference.

Comment: @mgilson I wasn't thinking about the distinction between class and instance members so I appreciate the clarification. In this particular case I am only using `__g/setattr__` to look for the names of the children so it will be OK to look for attributes of the instance. `hasattr` calls `__getattr__` and causes a recursion error for my design.